# не отображаются иконочные шрифты

Tags: css, .htaccess

у меня в файле .htaccess вот такая запись:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

то есть всегда подгружается индексный файл, какой uri не был бы введен (это особенность точки доступа)

Но вот у меня перестают подгружаться с этой записью иконки(квадратики только вижу), хотя стили css нормально работают.

Вот так подключаю иконки:     `<link href="fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--load all styles -->`

беру иконки с сайта https://fontawesome.com/

без этих строчек в .htaccess иконки работают нормально

Comment: fontawesome - это папка ?

Comment: ну да. это папка

Comment: а попробуйте подключите с cdnjs - заработает ?

Comment: заработали, интересно. спасибо

Comment: У вас путь относительно текущего юрл указан `<link href="fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">` . Добавление слеша в начале должно помочь. `<link href="/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">` (при условии что fontawesome - лежит в корне сайта).

Comment: добавлял, не помогало

Comment: @Александр Лиссов ....если хотите давайте в тем вивер, по любому разберусь что не работает

Comment: спасибо, но все заработало после того, как добавил пару строчек в .htaccess: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d